Is there a way to make tikz draw straight arrows between nodes automatically
I'm creating flowchart diagrams on tikz. My diagrams mostly are simple, vertical, like this:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) [process] {A};
    \node (b) [process, below=of a] {B};
    \node (c) [process, below=of b] {C};
    \node (d) [process, below=of c] {D};
    \node (e) [process, below=of d] {E};
    
    \draw [arrow] (a) -- (b);
    \draw [arrow] (b) -- (c);
    \draw [arrow] (c) -- (d);
    \draw [arrow] (d) -- (e);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

In this type of diagrams, arrows are of single type, and it's tedious to specify them in order to get correct diagram. I would like to know is there a way to just write one command and arrows are drawn automatically?
Also, I'd like to know if there is a way to just specify something like below instead of below=of <node_name> for nodes.

Please note that \tikzstyle is deprecated. Have a look at \tikzset instead.

I believe both the chains as well as the graphs library will help you.
The graphs library allows more flexibility via keys and its input syntax which is why it would be my choice.
Code
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, graphs, shapes.geometric}
\tikzset{% common
  il common/.style={
    shape=rectangle, draw=black, minimum width=+3cm, minimum height=+1cm},
  il process/.style={il common, fill=orange!30},
  il decision/.style={il common, shape=diamond, fill=green!30},
  il join/.style={thick, -Stealth}}

% chains library
\tikzset{
  every tikzchain/.style={
    nodes={il process, on chain, join=by il join},
    start chain=going below}}
\newcommand*\tikzchain[2][]{\tikz[every tikzchain,#1]\foreach\T in{#2}\node{\T};}

% graphs library
\tikzgraphsset{
  every tikzgraph/.style={
    nodes=il process, edge=il join,
    p/.style=il process, d/.style=il decision, % shortcuts
    branch down sep=+1cm, ->, path}}
\newcommand*\tikzgraph[2][]{\tikz\graph[every tikzgraph,#1]{#2};}
\begin{document}
\tikzchain{A, B, C, D, E}
\tikzgraph{A, B, C[d], D, E}
\end{document}

Output


I don't like diamonds for nodes with a lot of text, for an alternative, see A661558. (The linked answer even uses chains in graphs.)

Here is one way to do it: there are certainly more. Some remarks.

It's usually better, i.e. gives you more flexibility, to have your Tikz drawings as separate standalone documents. See integration examples e.g. here: "Out of page figure" or "Graph with legend".

In the spirit of refactoring it's probbaly useful to extract common options, like so; at least it makes code easier to digest:


\tikzstyle{common} = [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, common, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, common, fill=green!30]


Automatic node placement: introduce a \newcommand, e.g. \ndb (node below). As Pseudocode:

Place first node
Loop all the others

So, it looks like this in the code below:
% ~~~ shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\ndb[3]{\node (#1) [process, below=of #2] {#3};}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ you have to start somewhere ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (a) [process] {A};
    
    % ~~~ placing nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \b/\a/\t in {b/a/B, c/b/C, d/c/D, e/d/E}
        \ndb{\b}{\a}{\t};

Please note:

\b, \a and \t are variables you introduce (that's their function)
/ is a delimeter you chose to help Tikz separate the list
{ ... } indicates the set of data to loop
each set of data is comma separated, e.g. b/a/B, c/b/C, ...


Connecting can be done by a loop, too:

    % ~~~ connecting ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \a/\b in {a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e}
        \draw [arrow] (\a) -- (\b);

So, all you need to do ... is extending your two lists for the loops.


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}    % <<<
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, positioning}

\tikzstyle{common} = [minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, common, fill=orange!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, common, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

% ~~~ shortcuts ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\ndb[3]{\node (#1) [process, below=of #2] {#3};}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % ~~~ you have to start somewhere ~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node (a) [process] {A};
    
    % ~~~ placing nodes ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \b/\a/\t in {b/a/B, c/b/C, d/c/D, e/d/E}
        \ndb{\b}{\a}{\t};
        
    % ~~~ connecting ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \foreach \a/\b in {a/b, b/c, c/d, d/e}
        \draw [arrow] (\a) -- (\b);
    
    % ~~~ labels ~~~~~~~~
    \node[anchor=west] at (a.east) {initial node};
    \node[anchor=west] at (b.east) {looped nodes};
\end{tikzpicture}

% ~~~ original code ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) [process] {A};
    \node (b) [process, below=of a] {B};
    \node (c) [process, below=of b] {C};
    \node (d) [process, below=of c] {D};
    \node (e) [process, below=of d] {E};
    
    \draw [arrow] (a) -- (b);
    \draw [arrow] (b) -- (c);
    \draw [arrow] (c) -- (d);
    \draw [arrow] (d) -- (e);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


\tikzstyle is deprecated. if you are refactoring code, you should certainly replace it ;).

Thanks for your hint: that’s my current gray vs. grey puzzle …  ;-)

?? ............

One of both words or statements is correct … sometimes I have to look it up, if I want to spend that effort. grey? gray? black!50, same effect. Other things may be more important during that moment.

oh, well both gray and grey are correct in different variants of English, so I didn't get the analogy. (but pgf is US-centric, so it wants gray ;).)
